# What is the difference between wxPythons Super method and subclassing a widget such as a button?

Tags: wxpython, toggle, subclass

Can some one please explain the difference/advantages to using a wxPython widget subclass versus super()? I'm trying to create a toggle button without the enclosing border rectangle and I want to use the GenStaticBitmap from  the wx.lib.statbmp module as the base class.

I'm trying to pass three bitmaps to the subclass but have had no success in getting either approach to work. I'm not sure how to construct the subclass and pass the arguments or use super to create the class.

(I have more than 30 buttons to create which is why I'm trying to subclass the control)

The code works when placed in a panel as a GenStaticBitmap
Thanks for any help or advice.

This is what I've tried:

```
class MyBitmapButton(gen_statbmp.GenStaticBitmap):
    """ This is the subclassed version of the GenStaticBitmap to allow embedding bitmaps in the button"""
    def __init__(self, parent, off_bmp,on_bmp,hover_bmp):
        gen_statbmp.GenStaticBitmap.__init__(parent,id,off_bmp)
        self.bmapoff = off_bmp
        self.bmapon = on_bmp
        self.bmaphover= over_bmp
        self.state='off'
    def On_Hover(self,event):
        self.SetBitmap(self.bmphover)
        print 'on hover button state is',self.state
    def On_Leave(self,event):       
        #print 'on enter button state is',self.state
        if self.state=='on':
            print self.state
            self.SetBitmap(self.bmapon)
            self.state='on'
        if self.state=='off':
            self.SetBitmap(self.bmapoff)
            self.state='off'
        print 'on leave button state is',self.state
    def On_Click(self,event):
        #print 'on enter button state is',self.state
        if self.state=='on':
            print self.bmapbtn.state
            self.SetBitmap(self.bmapoff)
            self.state='off'
        elif self.state=='off':
            self.SetBitmap(self.bmapon)
            self.state='on'
        print 'on leave button state is',self.state
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wxPython archives explain the whole "super" ideology:

http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Super-object-usage-explanation-td3408498.html

If you're trying to create a custom widget, you should take a look at the wx.lib widgets. I think they're all custom widgets.

See also:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/CreatingCustomControls
- http://zetcode.com/wxpython/customwidgets/

Comment: Thanks Mike, the links provided the info I needed.